# SQL Server : getting year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15dd/1

What I want to do is display the latest year and month where trades were made.

In this case, i want to display

```
ID: 1  
Year: 2013  
Month: 11  
Trades: 2
```

I've tried to use:

```
select 
    id, MAX(year), MAX(month) 
from 
    ExampleTable
where 
    trades > 0
group by 
    id
```

Do I have to concatenate the columns?

Comment: The question is not very clear, can you explain more?

Comment: Yeah, its a bit fuzzy. 
Lets say I want to keep track of customer with ID 1's trades.
I want to see year and month of when he last made atleast 1 trade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to assign each row a number based on it's relative position (as defined by your order by):

```
SELECT  ID,
        Year,
        Month,
        Trades,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC)
FROM    ExampleTable
WHERE   Trades > 0;
```

With your example data this gives:

```
ID  YEAR    MONTH   TRADES  RowNum
1   2013    11      2       1
1   2013    4       42      2
```

Then you can just limit this to where `RowNum` is 1:

```
SELECT  ID, Year, Month, Trades
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Year,
                    Month,
                    Trades,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC)
            FROM    ExampleTable
            WHERE   Trades > 0
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.RowNum = 1;
```

If, as in your example, `Year` and `Month` are stored as `VARCHAR` you will need to convert to an `INT` before ordering:

```
RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID 
                            ORDER BY 
                                CAST(Year AS INT) DESC, 
                                CAST(Month AS INT) DESC)
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a15dd0/2)**

If you are only bothered about records where ID is 1, you can do it simply using `TOP`:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 ID, Year, Month, Trades
FROM    ExampleTable
WHERE   ID = 1
AND     Trades > 0
ORDER BY CAST(Year AS INT) DESC, CAST(MONTH AS INT) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why store "year" and "month" as separate columns?  In any case, the basic logic is to combine the two values to get the latest one.  This is awkward because you are storing numbers as strings and the months are not zero-padded.  But it is not so hard:

```
select id,
       max(year + right('00' + month, 2))
from ExampleTable
group by id;
```

To separate them out:

```
select id,
       left(max(year + right('00' + month, 2)), 4) as year,
       right(max(year + right('00' + month, 2)), 2) as month
from ExampleTable
group by id;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a15dd/9) is a SQL Fiddle.  Note when you use SQL Fiddle that you should set the database to the correct database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
  SELECT TOP 1 year + '-' + month AS Last, trades
    FROM ExampleTable
   WHERE CAST(trades AS INTEGER) > 0
ORDER BY CAST(year AS integer) DESC, CAST(month AS integer) DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a15dd/19/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1  ID, [year], trades,
              MAX(Convert(INT,[month])) OVER(PARTITION BY [year]) AS [Month]
FROM ExampleTable 
WHERE trades > 0
```